# Why is JSF output not being updated to reflect a change in my database?

Tags: java, jsf

I am using JSF as my front end technology. I have a list of locations that I am displaying on a table. I have a delete commandbutton that successfully deletes the selected entry from the database (by calling the deleteLocation method in the managed bean) and then refreshes the JSF page. Although the database updates correctly, the JSF page doesn't show the updated results. I'm not sure what the problem is as the table is generated from the database entries and the database is changed successfully. Here is my code. Thanks for any help or suggestions!

```
<tr>
        <td><div class="white"><H2>Work Locations</H2></div>
            <div class="tables"><h:dataTable value="#{locationsBean.locationsList}" var="l" border="1">

                <div class="td"><h:column>
                <div class="th"><f:facet name="header">
                <div class="generaltext3">County</div>
                </f:facet></div>
                <div class="generaltext2">#{l.countyName}</div>
                </h:column></div>
                <div class="td"><h:column>
                <div class="th"><f:facet name="header">
                <div class="generaltext3">Action</div>
                </f:facet></div>
                <div class="centrebutton"><h:commandButton id="delete" class="myButton2" value="delete" action="#{locationsBean.deleteLocation(l.location_id)}">
                </h:commandButton></div>
              </h:column></div>
            </h:dataTable></div>

            </td>
        </tr>
```

Here is the Java code

```
public List<Locations> getLocationsList() {
    factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);
    EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();   
    List<Locations> locationsList = new ArrayList<Locations>();

    em.getTransaction().begin();

        String sessionEmail=Util.getEmail();
        Query myQuery = em.createQuery("SELECT u FROM BusinessAccount u WHERE u.email=:email");
        myQuery.setParameter("email", sessionEmail);

        List<BusinessAccount> userList=myQuery.getResultList();
        BusinessAccount account =userList.get(0);

        locationsList=account.getLocations();
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.close();

        return locationsList;

    }

public String deleteLocation(int id) {
    factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);
    EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();   

        em.getTransaction().begin();
        Query myQuery = em.createQuery("SELECT l FROM Locations l WHERE l.location_id=:locationId");
        myQuery.setParameter("locationId", id);
        List<Locations> currentLocation=myQuery.getResultList();
        String countyName=currentLocation.get(0).getCountyName();
        em.remove(currentLocation.get(0));
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.close();

        this.getLocationsList();

        return "delete";
    }
```

Comment: `HTML` you posted is not a valid `XHTML`. Second `<div class="td">` does not have its closing counterpart.

Comment: That div is closed off after the </h:column> tag. My code works apart from the problem with updating the jsf page after the db has been changed so not sure what you mean by saying it's not xhtml. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public List<Locations> getLocationsList() {
    factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);
    EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();   
    em.getTransaction().begin();

        String sessionEmail=Util.getEmail();
        Query myQuery = em.createQuery("SELECT u FROM BusinessAccount u WHERE u.email=:email");
        myQuery.setParameter("email", sessionEmail);

        List<BusinessAccount> userList=myQuery.getResultList();         
        BusinessAccount account =userList.get(0);

        //This line refreshes the account object with the new values from the database and solves the problem that I was having
        em.refresh(account);

        locationsList=account.getLocations();
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.close();

        return locationsList;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `deleteLocation` method, you call `getLocationList`, which creates a *new* `List` and returns it. So by calling `this.getLocaitonList()` it does absolutely nothing. It's like saying `new String("Hello");` all by itself without assigning it to anything.

What you *should* do is assign your `List` bean field to `getLocationList` in your `deleteLocation` method. Something like

```
em.getTransaction().commit();
em.close();
//this.getLocaitonList();
locationList = getLicationList();
return "delete";
```

---

**SIDE NOTE**

You should consider using a three tier design

- Web tier (JSF Managed Bean)
- Business tier (EJB)
- Persistence tier (JPA)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm definately going to do what you said with the three tier design. The solution you gave didn't solve my problem but thanks for trying. Figured it out in the end thou. will show it in an answer.